# How to sanitize parameters for use in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, xss

I have the following php code:

```
<?php $redirect_lp = $_GET['lp']; ?>
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href = "<?php echo $redirect_lp; ?>";
    }, 10)
</script>
```

how do I sanitize `$redirect_lp`?

I know this code is bad because of this attack:

http://example.com/index.php?lp="-alert("XSS\n\n"%2bdocument.domain)-"

to protect from this particular attack, I santizie for `"`:

```
$redirect_lp = str_replace("\"", "", $redirect_lp);
```

is this enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First remove all illegal characters from the `$redirect_lp` variable, then check if it is a valid URL:

```
<?php 
   $redirect_lp = $_GET['lp']; 

   // Remove all illegal characters from a url
   $redirect_lp = filter_var($redirect_lp, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
?>
<?php if (filter_var($redirect_lp, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)): ?>
    <script>
       setTimeout(function(){
           window.location.href = "<?php echo $redirect_lp; ?>";
       }, 10)
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of ways you can [**filter a string in PHP**](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_filter.asp). Here's one way to sanitize a `URL`:

```
// Remove all illegal characters from a url
filter_var($redirect_lp, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
```

Or alternatively you can filter the input as you get it:

```
$redirect_lp = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'lp', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to use the function `htmlspecialchars()` whenever you want to output something to the browser that came from the user input.

The correct way to use something like this (enough to prevent XSS-attack):

```
echo htmlspecialchars($redirect_lp, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

After this kind of sanitation that you can validate url (`filter_var()` with `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` flag) and allow further steps to redirect user to specified page if validation passed of course.

P.S: You also might want to use `strip_tags()`, but keep in mind that it removes tags but not special characters like `"` or `'`, so if you use `strip_tags()` you also have to use `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: This is incorrect because URL's are encoded differently.  This is correct when dealing with HTML though.